# how to save multiple selection of listbox to database without comma separated in a column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, listbox

I am working on asp .net c# web application. I have two listbox, two textbox for SubmissionDate and SubmittedFee. One is called Project and set as single selection. Another listbox is called Client and set as multiple selection. For backend database, I have created a table called Project with  ProjectID, ProjectName, and ProjectTitle. Client table has ClientID, ClientName, and Address, etc. I have created another table called Submission for joining these two tables by SubID, SubDate, SubFee, ProjectID, ClientID. When a user selects one Project and two Clients from these listboxes together with SubDate and SubmittedFee, how can I save them in database along with SubmissoinDate and SubmittedFee. I do not want to save clients as delimited comma separated in database column. So, each time a user select more than one clients(e.g. three clients selected in listbox), my table should have three records of same SubID, same SubDate, same SubFee, same Project ID, and three different clients. I should be able to retrieve these three clients based on project ID as well. Can any one share any sample code or advice how I approach. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: In database there is One to many kind of relationship between tables.

you can use that, So here in your scenario 1(Project)=> many(Client) relationship is maintained.

Comment: I recomment you take a look at the "how to ask a question" guidelines here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Understand that part. How's about c# codes that I need to write Insert statement based on my requirements. I know how to write single selection of each list box. Not for multiple single selection. Should I used with foreach loop. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

In database there is One to many kind of relationship between tables. you can use that, So here in your scenario 
`1(Project)=> many(Client)` relationship is maintained. 
Have a look to http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

then your table structure will be something like::

```
CREATE TABLE Project (ProjectID,ProjectName,ProjectTitle)
CREATE TABLE Client (ClientID, ClientName,Address, ProjectID,..)
```

so whenever you are selecting Clients based on your `ProjectID` you need to do Group By while querying into your client table as::

```
select * from Client GroupBy ProjectID
```

then you will get proper result on the basis of relationship.